# Capitalizing vowels without replace/regex/includes

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to make that thing work but the output is probably not too far from the expected result - yet still ,not the correct output.

```
flipCase();
function flipCase() {
  var string = prompt("Please enter a string:");
  var vowels = "aeiou";
  var newString = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++) {
      if (string.charAt(i) === vowels.charAt(j)) {
        newString += string.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
      } else {
        newString += string.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(newString);
}
```

The input is : `open`.

The output is : `oooOopppppeEeeennnnn`.

The expected output is : `OpEn`.

Comment: Why not just have one loop and use `if (vowels.indexOf(string[i]) > -1)`?

Answer (score 2):

If you found a vowel, you need to leave the inner loop and omit adding the character to the result string.

```js
function flipCase(string) {
    string = string || prompt("Please enter a string:");
    const vowels = "aeiou";
    let newString = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        let character = string[i].toLowerCase();
        for (let j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++) {
            if (character === vowels[j]) {
                character = character.toUpperCase();
                break;
            }
        }
        newString += character;
    }
    return newString;
}

console.log(flipCase('open'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the index of each character in the string against against the vowels string using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). This way there's no nested loop.

```js
function flipCase(str) {

  const vowels = 'aeiou';

  let newString = '';

  // Iterate through the string - if the
  // (lowercase) character in the current iteration
  // is in the vowels string, make it uppercase, and
  // add it to `newString`, otherwise just add it
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const char = str[i].toLowerCase();
    if (vowels.indexOf(char) > -1) {
      newString += char.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      newString += char;
    }
  }

  return newString;

}

console.log(flipCase('open'));
console.log(flipCase('OPEN'));
console.log(flipCase('OPeN'));
console.log(flipCase('Gah! Homework :)'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks homework-like enough that I'm not going to just give you the full answer, but I'll get you halfway there:

```js
function flipCase() {
  var string = "here is some sample input"; // prompt doesn't work in SO snippets in some browsers
  var vowels = "aeiou";
  var newString = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++) {
      if (string.charAt(i) === vowels.charAt(j)) {
        newString += string.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
      }
      // the "else" can't go here, or it'll emit once for each
      // vowel whether it matches the current character or not.
    }
    // you need to output consonants outside the 'vowel' loop,
    // but this will also emit if the current character is a
    // vowel:
    newString += string.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
    // ...so you'll need to wrap the above in some other
    // condition to tell it when not to output. Possibilities
    // include checking specifically for not-a-vowel, or
    // setting a temporary variable whenever you output a vowel
    // that can be read here to prevent outputting it again
  }

  console.log(newString);
}

flipCase();
```

Comment: FYI you can use `prompt` in SO snippets just fine. I don't because it makes code arduous to test.

Comment: I get "Use of window.prompt is not allowed in different origin-domain iframes" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Might just be a difference in browsers. I use FF.

Comment: you're right, just checked and chrome allows it too, but Safari complains. I updated the comment

Answer (score 1):

```js
const vowels = "aeiou";

function isVowel(ch) {
  for (let i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
    if (vowels.charAt(i) === ch) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

function flipCase() {
  const string = "Please enter a string:";

  let newString = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    const ch = string.charAt(i);
    const chLower = ch.toLowerCase();

    if (isVowel(chLower)) {
      if (ch === chLower) {
        newString += ch.toUpperCase();
      } else {
        newString += ch.toLowerCase();
      }
    } else {
      newString += ch;
    }
  }

  console.log(newString);
}

flipCase();
```